# Media Player Solution

Tags: wpf, mediaelement, crash

We need to develop an application, which can play six videos concurrently.
we develop a test project first.
With 
OS : Windows 7 64bit
Platform : .net framework 4.0
Language : C#
Application Type : WPF
CPU:i5-3450 3.10GHz
RAM: 16GB

This is a pretty simple project. Loop a fixed folder and random pick a video file then play using MediaElement.
This application will run without any problem, but two or three hours later it will crash with exception:
AppCrash Module:KERNELBASE.dll
but unable to catch any exception, just crash.

Is there anyone with the same problem ?
Any solution ?

if Test project is required pls let me know. Thanks

Comment: Instead of running it, try debugging it in visual studio. Also try surrounding it in a `try` `catch ` block.

Comment: You could try looking in the Event Log

Comment: with
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException;
            this.DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
none exception will be caught.

Comment: What I mean by `try/catch` is go to the `main()` method and surround everything in the method with a `try { }` block, followed by a `catch` where you'll put your breakpoint and print out the exception, log it, etc.

Comment: Yeap, we had try catch every method. But no exception caught.

Comment: You may download our test project at :
http://www.everbox.com/f/jsPCpP2WBfYj7aZO34VdJRt6qt